# Is there a way to generate lags in a panel without collapsing the data?

Tags: panel, stata

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
State     Year      Policy      other_variables
 a        2000        0               18
 a        2000        0               19
                  .
                  .
                  .
 a        2001        1               86
 a        2001        1               23
```

The poicy value is constant within each state and year. But it changes for different state and different year. The other_variables are different for each observation.

I want to generate lags of the policy value for each state. However, I cannot use `xtset state year` and then use the `L` operator. There are repeated values within each state year combination. I know that collapsing the dataset, generate lag variables and then merge back to the dataset would work. My question is is there an easy way to do this operation?

Comment: As you have repeated values, what is your definition of the previous value so that we can advise how to calculate it? Do you e.g. want to calculate the difference between the means for each state and year?

Comment: I will edit the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:

```
clear 
input str1 State     Year      Policy    
 a        2000        0               
 a        2000        0               
 a        2001        1               
 a        2001        1               
 end 

 bysort State (Year) : gen diff = Policy - Policy[_n-1] if Year == Year[_n-1] + 1 
 by State Year: replace diff = diff[_n-1] if missing(diff) 

 list, sepby(State Year) 

     +------------------------------+
     | State   Year   Policy   diff |
     |------------------------------|
  1. |     a   2000        0      . |
  2. |     a   2000        0      . |
     |------------------------------|
  3. |     a   2001        1      1 |
  4. |     a   2001        1      1 |
     +------------------------------+
```

Comment: I modified the answer slightly and get what I want. Thanks!